# Reconstrcuting images from MPEG

Tags: video, mpeg

I wish to export all frames of an MPEG video as individual frames.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Export it from any transcoding software to a frame by frame format such as motion JPEG or an actual image sequence.

Answer (score 0):

[MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) has GUI and command line options to extract JPEGs for frames. You could give it the following command line, for example, to get 1000 frames out of the specified video:

```
mplayer -vo jpeg -frames 1000 my_video.mpg
```

Comment: I wish to extract the reference frames and intermediate frames. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use ffmpeg.

```
mkdir video_seq
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 video_seq/video_%05d.png
```